# Filter array of objects with muliple values

Tags: javascript

I have two Arrays of Objects. While `localDataArray` is is already stored inside my app,`remoteUpdateDataArray` comes from the backend.

```
var localDataArray =   [
    { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"}, 
    { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"},
    { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"}
];


var remoteUpdateDataArray =   [
     { "date": "12/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "4a0a19218e082a343a1b17e5333409af9d98f0f5"}, 
     { "date": "11/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"}, 
     { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"}, 
     { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"},
     { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"}
];
```

I want to remove all duplicated objects from `remoteUpdateDataArray`. The unique identifier of each object is the hash.

So far, I have the following code:

```
let hashValue = "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"

var filteredResult = remoteUpdateDataArray.filter(x => x.hash !== hashValue);
```

Result:

```
var filteredResult =   [
         { "date": "12/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "4a0a19218e082a343a1b17e5333409af9d98f0f5"}, 
         { "date": "11/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"}, 
         { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"}, 
         { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"}
    ];
```

How  do I manage to also get rid of the other (in this case two duplicate objects) inside the array? Keep in mind that these arrays may get pretty big.

Comment: Why did you mention `localDataArray` if it actually doesn't matter for your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd build a list of hashes from your first array (to save iterations), then simply filter using includes()

```js
const inLocalData = localDataArray.map(({hash: e}) => e);
const result = remoteUpdateDataArray.filter(({hash: e}) => ! inLocalData.includes(e));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
var localDataArray = [{
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"
  }
];


var remoteUpdateDataArray = [{
    "date": "12/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "4a0a19218e082a343a1b17e5333409af9d98f0f5"
  },
  {
    "date": "11/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, was almost there! This one is working like a charm. Will consider the other solutions when it comes to performance optimizing.

Comment: @bambam This code works fine with the given data set. But what if there are duplicate elements in the `remoteUpdateDataArray` (which it is in the given data set) and that element is **not present** in the `localDataArray`? In that case, the duplicate elements are not filtered out. I just tested it. You might have to modify the code a bit.

Comment: Which of the duplicates (if any) in remoteDataArray should be kept @MarcJohnson the first or the latest?

Comment: @bambam I would got for the latest!

Answer (score 1):

It seems U need a cache. Store the hash into the cache, and update it while U get new data.

```
var localDataArray =   [
    { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"}, 
    { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"},
    { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"}
];

var cache = {}

// The result, make a copy of local data at start
var filtered = [].concat(localDataArray)

// initialize the cache
localDataArray.forEach(item => {
    cache[item.hash] = true
})

// -----------

var remoteUpdateDataArray =   [
     { "date": "12/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "4a0a19218e082a343a1b17e5333409af9d98f0f5"}, 
     { "date": "11/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"}, 
     { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "surf", "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"}, 
     { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"},
     { "date": "10/01/19", "category": "skate", "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"}
];

// filter duplicated items
remoteUpdateDataArray.forEach(item => {
    // item exists
    if(cache.hasOwnProperty(item.hash)) {
        return
    }
    // append hash and item
    cache[item.hash] = true
    // just append the new data items
    filtered.push(item)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqBy) from lodash?

first, join the 2 arrays with spred opertaor(you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)):

```
const newArray = [...localDataArray ,...remoteUpdateDataArray];
```

and when you have the new array with all the duplications

```
const filteredResult = _.uniqBy(newObject,'hash');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also

```js
var localDataArray = [{
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"
  }
];
var remoteUpdateDataArray = [{
    "date": "12/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "4a0a19218e082a343a1b17e5333409af9d98f0f5"
  },
  {
    "date": "11/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "surf",
    "hash": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "a0f1490a20d0211c997b44bc357e1972deab8ae3"
  },
  {
    "date": "10/01/19",
    "category": "skate",
    "hash": "54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b"
  }
];


let data =[];

localDataArray.map(item=>{
 data= remoteUpdateDataArray.find(el=>item.hash!=el.hash)
  
})

console.log(data)
```